# SAS9.4 How to sum values over a range of dates?

Tags: sas

```
PatientID  SvcDate      OpCode   Pay
---------- --------     -------  ----
101        01/13/2013    19       30.7
101        01/14/2013    12       11.3
101        01/16/2013    13       28.0
101        01/16/2013    12       60.2
101        02/09/2013    10       11.4
102        02/10/2013    12        9.2
102        02/10/2013    19       13.2
102        02/11/2013    13       32.1
102        02/12/2013    14       17.5
102        02/13/2013    15       10.2
102        02/19/2013    12       14.3
```

Hello,

I am trying to sum up the `Pay` variable for the observations that are 2 days before and 2 days after the observation with `Opcode = 13`.

For example,

for `PatientID = 101`, the  `Opcode = 13` observation falls on `SVCDate = 01/16/2013`, so I would like to sum up all the `Pay` values for `SVCDate = 01/14/2013` to `SVCDate = 01/18/2013`. So this would include the observations for `PatientID = 101` where `Pay` variable is `11.3`, `28.0`, and `60.2`.

Thus,  the operation would be `11.3 + 28.0 + 60.2 = 99.5`.

I would like to put this `99.5` into a new table that has 2 variables:

`PatientID` and `DirectProcedureCost`. `DirectProcedureCost` for `Patient 101` would be `99.5`.

I would like to loop through all my patient IDs and be able to obtain the `DirectProcedureCost` for each one. What would be the best way in SAS9.4 to do this?

Comment: Please remember to include what you've tried in the future per [ask]

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to SAS, I suggest you to use it in easy way.

```
data have;
input PatientID SvcDate :mmddyy10. OpCode Pay;
format SvcDate mmddyy10.;
datalines;
101 01/13/2013 19 30.7
101 01/14/2013 12 11.3
101 01/16/2013 13 28.0
101 01/16/2013 12 60.2
101 02/09/2013 10 11.4
102 02/10/2013 12 9.2
102 02/10/2013 19 13.2
102 02/11/2013 13 32.1
102 02/12/2013 14 17.5
102 02/13/2013 15 10.2
102 02/19/2013 12 14.3
;
run;

proc sort;
  by PatientID SvcDate;
run;

/*Get List of Date(InDt) from SvcDate - 2 to SvcDate + 2*/
data m1;
  set have(where=(OpCode=13));
  do InDt = SvcDate - 2 to SvcDate + 2;
    output;
  end;
run;

/*Get observations whose SvcDate falls in 'InDt'*/
data m2;
  merge m1(in=_major_) have(rename=(SvcDate=InDt OpCode=InOpCode Pay=InPay));
  by PatientID InDt;
  if _major_;
run;

/*Sumup InPay on each rows by every single PatientID*/
data m3;
  set m2;
  by PatientID;
  if first.PatientID then DirectProcedureCost = .;
  DirectProcedureCost + InPay;
  if last.PatientID then output;
  drop InDt InOpCode InPay;
run;
```

If you have good SQL practice experience, @Richard has a nice example for you.
If you have at least primary level of SAS programming and want to turn it up to eleven, I would recommend you to learn about `table lookup`([link](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings15/2219-2015.pdf)). The method of using Hash from @draycut 's anwser is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach.

Let me know if this works for you and feel free to ask.

```
data have;
input PatientID SvcDate :mmddyy10. OpCode Pay;
format SvcDate mmddyy10.;
datalines;
101 01/13/2013 19 30.7
101 01/14/2013 12 11.3
101 01/16/2013 13 28.0
101 01/16/2013 12 60.2
101 02/09/2013 10 11.4
102 02/10/2013 12 9.2
102 02/10/2013 19 13.2
102 02/11/2013 13 32.1
102 02/12/2013 14 17.5
102 02/13/2013 15 10.2
102 02/19/2013 12 14.3
;

data want;

   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      dcl hash h(dataset : "have", multidata : "Y");
      h.definekey("PatientID", "SvcDate");
      h.definedata("Pay");
      h.definedone();
   end;

   set have;
   where OpCode = 13;

   DirectProcedureCost = 0;

   do dt = SvcDate - 2 to SvcDate + 2;
      do while(h.do_over(key : PatientID, key : dt) = 0);
         DirectProcedureCost + Pay;
      end;
   end;

   keep PatientID DirectProcedureCost;
run;
```

Result:

```
PatientID DirectProcedureCost 
101       99.5 
102       82.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Proc SQL` to compute values about a target row.

SQL queries are understood by many SAS and non-SAS coders.

Example:

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    Center.PatientID
    , Center.SvcDate as Op13Date
    , sum(Pay) as DirectProcedureCost label='5 day costs centered on OpCode 13'
  from
    (select PatientID, SvcDate from have where OpCode = 13) as Center
  join 
    have
  on 
    have.PatientID = Center.PatientID
  & have.SvcDate between Center.SvcDate-2 and Center.SvcDate+2
  group 
    by Center.PatientID, Center.SvcDate
  order
    by Center.PatientID
  ;
```

A more complex query would be needed if the data might contain and medical service policy allows a patient to have OpCode = 13 service within 2 days of another OpCode = 13